# How to check if a list has a certain element in it

Tags: python, list

```
my_list = ["hi", "bye", "hi"]
```

Say I don't know what is in `my_list`, how can I check if `"bye"` is an element in my list.  And if `"bye"` is an element in `my_list`, then how can I know which index it has (for this case `"bye"` is in `my_list[1]`)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> how can I check if "bye" is an element in my list.

```
"bye" in my_list
```

> then how can I know which index it is

```
my_list.index("bye")
```

You can skip the first step because if you try to find the index of a value that isn't in the list, you will get a value error which you can handle like this:

```
try:
    my_list.index("not here")
except ValueError:
    print("'not here' isn't in the list!!")
```

Comment: And for a sufficiently long list, you *should* go to the try/except version, because otherwise you have to traverse the list twice and that's slow :P

Answer (score 2):

```
try:
    idx = ['hi', 'bye', 'hi'].index('bye')
except ValueError:
    print('Not in list.')
else:
    print('In list at index', idx)
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try `list.index`.

```
try:
    i = my_list.index('hi')
except ValueError:
    i = False
```

i will hold the index if `hi` is in the list, otherwise it will be False, because `list.index` raises ValueErrror if it can't return the index.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [in](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#in) operator to check if a specific item exists in a list. To find the index of any item in a list just use the `.index()` function. If you are a beginner in Python you can use the below method else you can check out [exception handling](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_exceptions.htm).

```
my_list = ["hi", "bye", "hi"]
if 'bye' in my_list:
   print "Word found at index %i",my_list.index('bye')
else
   print 'Word not Found !'
```